# Proof methods Discrete Math

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Claim: for any integers m and n, if $7m + 5n = 147,\,$ then $m$ is odd or $n$ is odd

a) state the converse of the claim
b) state the contrapositive of the claim.
c) use proof by contrapositive to prove the claim.

my solutions:
let "$7m + 5n = 147$" $= p$ and "m is odd or n is odd" $= q$.

a) q implies p

b) negation of q implies negation of p

c) ??

Comment: HINT: If $m,n$ are both odd, $7m+5n$ is even

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you *write out* in words, what the converse and contrapositive would each assert. You are correct in your logic about an implication $p \rightarrow q$. But what exactly is "not $q\;?$ That's crucial here. And for that matter, what exactly is "not $p$?

For $(b, c)$

We have $q$: Either $m$ is odd, or $n$ is odd.

Let $M$ denote "m is odd", and let $N$ denote "n is odd". So, in fact, $q = M \lor N$. So the negation is $$\lnot q \equiv \lnot(M \lor N) \equiv (\lnot M \land \lnot N)$$

Hint on $(c)$: Start $(c)$ by assuming $\lnot q$: Assume neither $m$ is odd, nor $n$ is odd...put differently, this amounts to the assertion "$m$ is even and $n$ is even." Then argue that this implies $$\lnot p \equiv  7m + 5n \neq 147$$

Comment: Nice write - up +1

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks for the support! Hope *you're* feeling back to your "ole" self! (Nasty bee sting!!)